# Facing a problem related to number of render samples,how to set the number of samples to 128 again after changing it?

Tags: rendering

Recently I changed the number of render samples from 128 to 510 for a specific model. but now even if I'm opening a new blender file and, even though there is written(in render properties) that the number of render samples in the render is 128 and viewport is 32. Still when I press Render image the number of samples that are calculated are 510, and I'm not able to change it, please help.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not using branched path tracing? I don't really know any other way you can have more samples than what your base sample setting is, is by using sub samples in the branched path tracing mode, or by squaring the samples. But 128 squared is way more than 510. Otherwise I'm thinking of a bug of some sort.

Comment: Are you using a material override? https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4QaN.png

Comment: yes, I'm sure I'm not using Branched path tracing. Even though I completely close blender and start a new blender project. The render properties are not even tampered and the render samples are 128 (render ) and 32 (viewport), just when I think ok it should work fine now. when I render the ing, The information shown at the top bar while rendering, it shous

Comment: it shows (Rendered: 20/ 510 TIles)

Comment: Im sorry, im a beginner in the blender. i didn't know that 510 tiles are just the way it should be, sorry for bothering you guys.